# How to fix Python requests/BeautifulSoup response from database

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new to web scraping/coding, and I am trying to use Python requests/BeautifulSoup to parse through the html code in order to get some physical and chemical properties.

For some reason, although I have used the following script for other websites successfully, BeautifulSoup has only printed a few lines from the header and footer, and then pages of HTML code that doesn't really make sense. This is the code I have been using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://comptox.epa.gov/dashboard/dsstoxdb/results?search=ammonia#properties'
response = requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml') 
print(soup.prettify())
```

When I try to find the table or even a row, it gives no output. Is there something I haven't accounted for? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to read the source of this page ? Does it looks like the content of your output ? The answer is Yes because this website is using some sort of dom manipulator to load content, you'll be unable to scrap anything from here unless you can interpret javascript

Comment: I use selenium to pull up pages with javascript or to interact with them. Selenium allows clicking and other actions on a given webpage as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is present in one of the attributes. You can extract as follows (there is a lot more info there but I subset to physical properties

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

url = "https://comptox.epa.gov/dashboard/dsstoxdb/results?search=ammonia#properties"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
soup.select_one('[data-result]')['data-result']
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('[data-result]')['data-result'])
properties = data['physprop']
print(properties)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty common that if a page is populated by JavaScript after you load it `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` will not process the page correctly. The best thing to do is likely switch to [the `selenium` module](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which allows your program to dynamically access the page and interact with elements. After loading (and maybe clicking on a couple elements) you can feed the HTML to `BeautifulSoup` and process it how you wish. The basic framework I recommend you start with would look like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome() # You'll need to download drivers from link above
browser.implicitly_wait(10) # probably unnecessary, just makes sure all pages you visit fully load
browser.get('https://stips.co.il/explore')
while True:
    input('Press Enter to print HTML')
    HTML = browser.page_source
    print(HTML)
```

Just click around in the browser and when you want to see if the HTML is correct, click back to your prompt and press `ENTER`. [This is how you would locate elements automatically](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), so you don't have to manually interact with the page every time